# how to use hawt.io with spring boot and an embedded Jetty

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty, hawtio

I have an Apache camel application which starts as an 'fat-jar' including an Jetty server.
Is it possible to add hawt.io to the jar in order to use hawt.io for this application?

I tried to add hawt.io with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
    <artifactId>hawtio-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.47</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
    <artifactId>hawtio-plugin-mbean</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.47</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
    <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.47</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
    <artifactId>hawtio-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.47</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

but "/localhost:[my port]/hawtio" does not respond.

Comment: Se also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326149/how-to-run-hawt-io-in-spring-boot-application-with-embedded-tomcat/30505163#30505163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add some code to tell Jetty to add the hawtio-web WAR file as a context-path to jetty itself.

See how we do this from hawtio embedded

- https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/hawtio-embedded/src/main/java/io/hawt/embedded/Main.java