# Spring boot , apache camel and hawtio: cannot send message to endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, hawtio

I'm trying to integrate hawtio in a spring-boot application using apache camel. I followed [Spring-Boot Embedded Wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916935/spring-boot-embedded-wars/26089835#26089835) and added HawtioConfiguration from [How to run hawt.io in spring boot application with embedded tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326149/how-to-run-hawt-io-in-spring-boot-application-with-embedded-tomcat/30505163) (except for the kubeservice and kubepod which are not in io.hawt.web package)

So, that works, up to the point where I try to manualy send a message to a direct endpoint from the hawtio interface ( http://localhost:8080/hawtio/index.html#/camel/sendMessage?tab=camel&nid=root-org.apache.camel-camel-1-endpoints-%22direct:%2F%2Fdummy%22 ) . The following warning appears, and no message is sent:

```
Camel does not support sending to this endpoint.
```

So, did I forget anything ? Here is my set up : springboot 1.3.3.RELEASE with the following dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.64</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
        <artifactId>hawtio-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.64</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the Application.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHawtio
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.setProperty(AuthenticationFilter.HAWTIO_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED, "false");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        final ConfigManager configManager = new ConfigManager();
        configManager.init();
        servletContext.setAttribute("ConfigManager", configManager);
    }
}
```

Thanks !

edit: using hawtio as a standalone app and connecting to springboot works fine

edit2: moving on, I used hawtio as a war on another project (same version) , deployed on a tomcat 7. Same issue, cannot send to a direct endpoint. 
go figure.

Answer (score 0):

The option of using hawtio as war works very well with application using spring boot and camel, I am already using it successfully.
check the hawtio github code example, it contains good samples to try
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio

Also I will share my github link with sample's of using hawtio wat or as maven plug-in.

Comment: I got a war the hawtio website, and connecting to the spring boot via the 'connect' panel yield the same result. I can see and monitor my routes, but cannot send a message to one of them

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: I could not use hawt.io to send to a direct endpoint (nor any other endpoint). Maybe it is a general Bug/ unimplemented feature in hawt.io?

However, the following was possible:

- Copy the Endpoint URL
- Select the context node in hawt.io
- Click on "Operations"
- Use the method sendStringBody(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) to send a string to that endpoint
- First parameter is the endpoint URI that you can paste in